# Implementing imfilter(matlab) with opencv

Tags: matlab, opencv

I was trying to implement matlab's imfilter function in opencv. I found across this link which could help me [CLICK HERE](http://answers.opencv.org/question/8783/implement-imfiltermatlab-with-opencv/). That link has an answer which I am expecting. But the C++ code there is not complete. As I am new to opencv, I couldnt use the FilterEngine correctly. Anybody help me with the complete code along with the FilterEngine class.

Comment: What's wrong with `filter2D`? http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d - It's essentially the same as `imfilter`, provided that your convolution masks are symmetric.

Comment: @rayryeng, the answers are not matching with that of imfilter

Comment: You will never get the values between OpenCV and MATLAB to match up because the way the images are decoded between the two are slightly different.  If it is your personal mission to try and match up the outputs between both OpenCV and MATLAB, you'll be on that journey forever.

Comment: @rayryeng, got your point. I need to learn FilterEngine anyways. Help me in implementing FilterEngine in the code that link has(Link I specified in the question). Thanks in advance.

Comment: That link seems complete to me.  Why would it not be complete?

Comment: @rayryeng, Implementation of FilterEngine is not there. I am getting errors while running it.